# Let's design an ad for this site!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Would you like to design an ad for this site? We're seriously considering posting one on one or more of the [periodicals that people who come here read](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-jewish-print-periodicals-do-you-read) (feel free to add to that list). Please post ideas for ad concepts and/or pictures of actual ad designs as answers.

The ad should definitely contain a URL that gets you to this site. http://judaism.stackexchange.com is the obvious choice. http://mi.yodeya.com also points here and is an [unofficial alternate URL](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/proposed-faq-language-explaining-mi-yodeya-references).

Here are a couple of previous meta questions that could help give you ideas about what to express in an ad:

- [What's Our Elevator Pitch?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/whats-our-elevator-pitch)
- [What unique value does mi.yodeya offer?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-unique-value-does-mi-yodeya-offer)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try a rotation of different lines:

- Ask 2 Jews, Get 3 Answers. Mi.Yodeya.com
- Why do Jews always answer a question with a question? Why don't you ask it on Mi.Yodeya?
- A rabbi and a priest walk into a bar. The bartender says, "what about stam yayin"?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Venn diagram indicating that at intersection between "Ask Jewish Questions" and "Give Jewish Answers" lies "judaism.stackexchange.com" - "A free, community driven Q&A for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more."]

Comment: I like this!! But how many non-geeks would? :)

Comment: The motto at the bottom looks perhaps a bit too wordy in this context. (It may well be that it's too wordy for our FAQ, too, for that matter, but the task at hand is to design an ad.)

Comment: I was thinking of the bottom line more as body-copy than a motto. The motto would be "Ask Jewish Questions, Give Jewish Answers".

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using persistent small ads, versus sporadic large ones.

The ads could give examples of high-interest (and low-controversy) questions that will pique the readers' curiosity and prod them to visit the site. For example:

> "**What does the name Feivel mean?** Find the answer to this question and others on mi.yodeya.com."
>
> "**Was Eisav Jewish?** Find the answer to this question and others on mi.yodeya.com."
>
> ...and so forth.

If these ads are run on a consistent basis, people will get the idea that when they have an unanswered question (and who doesn't?), the place to go is mi.yodeya. Simplicity and repetition are key here.

Obviously the name question (mi.yodeya vs. judaism.SE) will need to be resolved beforehand.

Comment: I submit that the name question doesn't necessarily need to be resolved before using either name in ads. Many businesses use alternate URLs for publicity purposes that aren't the same as their business name. If mi.yodeya.com is an evocative enough URL, at least in certain markets, I don't see why we can't use it in ads in those markets, even if it's not the official name of the site.

Comment: With this concept, we could vary the questions seasonally, e.g. picking out Tishrei-related questions for issues that go out in the late Summer and Autumn.

Comment: @Isaac - uniformity would be a huge plus, but I guess it's not critical. WRT seasonal questions -- absolutely. But it would be prudent to avoid halachic questions, so as not to give the impression that we are issuing rulings from the net.

Comment: New question just came up that would be great for the ad: "Does the Torah discuss aliens?"

Comment: Why not controversial questions too? That always gets visitors. More than any questions about Feivel.

Comment: Asking a controversial question might give the impression that we are in a certain ideological box, or that this is a place where people regularly challenge accepted wisdom. It can also permanently alienate certain groups who are passionate about the issue in question. (Use your imagination...)

Answer (score 2):

Based on an idea msh210 [proposed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=1419606#1419606) in chat, here's a concept:

In the middle, "mi.yodeya.com" in big letters. Around the perimeter, a collection of topics covered here, separated by question marks. Also possibly throw the words "expert" and "novice" into the mix.

The idea is to intrigue people with the URL (which implies a question) and provide a little information about what's being dealt without trying to get into a full description of what SE is.

A possible addition would be to have in large text, in addition to the URL, something like "Who knows? Do you?" for added intrigue.

Comment: The surrounding text could be representative questions, as in [Dave's idea](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/319/lets-design-an-ad-for-this-site/325#325)