# Contact reporters to promote this site!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We'd like to start a community-based press outreach initiative, with the goal being newspaper and magazine stories about this site. Instead of trying to blast a formal press release out to as many reporters as possible and hope someone takes notice (been there; tried that; didn't work), we'd like to try a more focused approach: Each volunteer picks one newspaper or magazine at a time and then makes a concerted effort to get the attention of someone at that publication, using email, phone, etc.

Would you like to try your hand at volunteer press evangelism? Pick a publication from our [list](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-jewish-print-periodicals-do-you-read) of periodicals that people who come here read (feel free to add to the list!). Post an answer here "claiming" that periodical. Then go through the publication's staff list and find editors or writers who you think may be interested in trying and covering this website, and try to make contact with them by email, phone, etc.

Here are some sources of talking points you can use:

- Our [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/about) pages.
- [What's Our Elevator Pitch?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/whats-our-elevator-pitch)
- [What unique value does this site offer?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-unique-value-does-mi-yodeya-offer)
- Your favorite content on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer claiming a periodical (as sought in the question), but rather a community-wiki answer which should be a boilerplate (template) for letters to newspaper staffers. Please contribute:

---

*(it goes here)*