# Is it time to replace the term CYLOR?

Tags: discussion

"CYLOR" (See your local Orthodox Rabbi) is a much-used phrase on Mi Yodeya, and throughout many Jewish sites.

I believe this innocuous phrase has several limitations. The first is a question of audience: An Orthodox Jew would know to ask an Orthodox Rabbi; while a non-Orthodox Jew may feel judged or confused.

In addition, not all Orthodox Rabbis are competent.
Additionally, the term "local" is mostly irrelevant. Many people have a connection with a solid Halachik authority who lives some distance away, and there is no reason that is any worse than a "local" one. (Perhaps the term local is a rather out-of-context translation of "marah d'asra".) In the same vein, the Rabbi does not have to be "your" Rabbi - complex or difficult questions may need a more highly qualified Halachik authority to pasken.

In our on-going effort to make Mi Yodeya more friendly, open, and conducive to Kiddush Hashem, (see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/how-should-we-ask-for-improvements-to-questions-and-answers?cb=1)and [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-unique-value-does-mi-yodeya-offer/108#108) for examples)I would like to suggest we search for alternatives to this common catch phrase.

A possibility is to replace CLYOR with ACR - Ask a Competent Rabbi.

What do you think about this situation? (Please write both pros and cons!)

What alternative phrases could we use?

Comment: I question how literally anyone takes the phrase.

Comment: @DoubleAA See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/ that this phrase is taken literally - including the "local" part

Comment: I don't see the phrase mentioned there at all...

Comment: @DoubleAA judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146 takes the "local" part very seriously. Although CYLOR isn't written, it is implied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Besides the drawbacks suggested in the question and in Monica Cellio's answer, "CYLOR" is not-universally-comprehensible jargon, and therefore, its use, at least in question and answer posts, is generally inconsistent with our [jargon policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/site-policy-on-jargon). In addition, its use, whether in posts, comments or chat, could come off as [excessively brusque](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/how-should-we-ask-for-improvements-to-questions-and-answers), where a complete, polite, tailored sentence is likely to be better-received.

Therefore, I recommend that in general, people who want to convey this sentiment use some variation, tailored to the context and the target for maximum effectiveness, of:

```
I recommend that you [consult your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146).
```

For a disclaimer at the end of a *Halacha* question, one could use something along the lines of:

```
Of course, [consult your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).
```

Comment: +1 similar answer: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2261/5323

Answer (score 7):

CYLOR long pre-dates Mi Yodeya; I first encountered it on soc.culture.jewish on Usenet *mumbledy* years ago.  So it seems natural to me that it migrated here.  (There I also saw a variant, CYLHA for "...Halachic Authority", but it was never as widespread and seems a little cumbersome to me.)

But over time, and particularly *here*, I too have found the term not ideal.  For a while I was using CYLR -- the "your" should already cover "of a flavor acceptable to you", after all.  Somebody, I forget who, pointed out to me that the same reasoning could apply to "local" -- you're going to consult *your* rabbi, who's probably local to you but "local" is more about relationship than geography.

So these days I tend to use CYR -- Consult Your Rabbi.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting it in the big warning on the page? Just make it "CYLOR: Call your Local Orthodox Rabbi" + currentScript